# create grails custom ResourceMapper

Tags: grails

I created the following resource mapper using the instructions from the resources plugin:

```
import org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.MapperPhase
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class VersionResourceMapper {

    def phase = MapperPhase.MUTATION
    def log = LogFactory.getLog(this.class)

    static defaultIncludes = [ '/js/**' ]

    def map(resource, config) {
        def query = [v:'1.01']
        resource.actualUrl = resource.actualUrl + '?' + query.collect { it }.join('&')
        //resource.updateActualUrlFromProcessedFile()

        if (log.debugEnabled) log.debug "Modified URL: ${resource.actualUrl}"
        log.info "Modified URL: ${resource.actualUrl}"
    }
}
```

The file is located in grails-app/resourceMappers

My class never even gets called.  I have a debug breakpoint set which is never hit.  Is there some other configuration that has to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line

static defaultIncludes = [ '/js/**' ]

and check if your breakpoint is hit. It looks like it is just not finding the js directory.

If that works change the above line to

static defaultIncludes = [ 'js/**' ]

Comment: This was close.  I had to do '**/css/**', '**/js/**'.  I think your solution would have worked on production but in development the resources were appended with /static.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you need to change

```
def phase = MapperPhase.MUTATION
```

to

```
 static phase = MapperPhase.MUTATION
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't change anything.  The debug breakpoint still doesn't get hit.

Comment: What version of grails and the resources plugin are you using?